# Google Datastore Auto Entity ID generation

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to get the entity Ids of Google Datastore auto generated by Google Datastore (I can't use uuid) in Apache Beam pipeline using python.

I'm using the following code to pass the entity kind and key values when building the entities in Datastore.

```
from googledatastore import helper as datastore_helper

entity = entity_pb2.Entity()
        datastore_helper.add_key_path(entity.key, entityName.get(), str(uuid.uuid4()))
```

in the above code, I can't use `uuid.uuid4()` to randomly generate unique Ids according to the project requirement. I have to use Google Datastore's auto Id generation. After a lot of reading, I am still unsure what to pass to the datastore helper to make it take care of the unique id generation without using uuids. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's an artifical limitation imposed by the sdk, by this `if` statement inside `WriteToDatastore`:

```
  if client_entity.key.is_partial:
    raise ValueError('Entities to be written to Cloud Datastore must '
                     'have complete keys:\n%s' % client_entity)
```

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.14.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/datastore/v1new/datastoreio.html#WriteToDatastore

Dataflow steps can be re-run a couple of times, so i think this limitation is there to prevent you from generating duplicate entries in your datastore.

The function behind `WriteToDatastore` is `batch.commit()` from the new 'cloud datastore' library https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/index.html (which is used in `write_mutations` in `apache_beam/io/gcp/datastore/v1/helper.py`):

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.14.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/datastore/v1new/helper.html#write_mutations

The primary `Client()` class in the Cloud Datastore library has an `allocate_ids()` function:
https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/client.html?highlight=allocate_ids#google.cloud.datastore.client.Client.allocate_ids

You should be able to use that to auto-gen ids for your entities before passing them to `WriteToDatastore`

Comment: I tried using allocate_ids() but i'm unable to get it to generate the ids. Can you give me more insights on how to make it return unique ids? Thanks.

Comment: Does it throw an exception? whats it returning?

Comment: I found that there are several allocate_ids() functions from different libraries . The appstore libraries are throwing package not found errors on dataflow and the googledatastore allocate_ids() is throwing invalid parameter. Can you show me a code snipet that returns the 16 digit unique id from google datastore when called? If I can get that, it would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud Datastore, if the numeric id for the entity is omitted when an entity is created, then datastore will generate one using the ‘kind’.

The allocateId() from the cloud datastore client API allows you to generate a block of IDs based on an incomplete/partial key, typically when only the namespace is specified. This can then be used as a base to allocate id’s.

More information along with some code snippets can be found at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#kinds_and_identifiers 
and also at

https://medium.com/google-cloud/entity-groups-ancestors-and-indexes-in-datastore-a-working-example-3ee40cc185ee

For usage information for google cloud datastore helper’s .add_key_path, the helper.py script is available at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/blob/master/python/googledatastore/helper.py.

Please reference as of line 153.